# perl compute difference of columns in csv file

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, diff

i've a csv file (very huge) with following format.

```
key1,val1,val2,val3... ,valn
key2,val2,val5,val1....,valn
...
...
keyn,val7,val9,val11....,valn
key1,val2,val4,val8.....,valn
key2,val10,val12,val14..., valn
...
...
keyn,val2,val4,val8.....,valn
key1,val3,val5,val7... ,valn
key2,val0,val9,val3....,valn
```

key1 to keyn (and their values) repeats multiple times in csv file.

values (val1, valn) are double(float).

what i want to print:

1) From the beginning of the file, for each key i want to calculate difference between column values (val2,val4,val6 for example) to the next occurrence of the key.

so for example

```
key1,2,4,6
key2,3,5,7
...
...
key1,4,6,8
key2,4,6,8
```

I want to print

key1: Diff from previous record is key1,2,2,2
key2: Diff from previous record is key2,1,1,1
..

keyn: Diff from previous record is ...........

2) Do this repeatedly for the each consecutive occurrences of each key.

Here's what i came up to (storing values in hash)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my %hash;
open my $fh, '<', 'file1.csv' or die "Cannot open: $!";
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
  $line =~ s/\s*\z//;
  my @array = split /,/, $line;
  my $key = shift @array;
  $hash{$key} = \@array;
}
close $fh;
```

Comment: sorry... for the bad id -:) it was quick post... i do have valid email address

Comment: @mystery_man I guess you are in good company http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austin_Powers:_International_Man_of_Mystery More importantly, you have not explained your problem well.

Comment: This feels familiar.  Homework?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  Are you looking for comments on your solution, better solutions, or bug fixing?  It would be nice if you could simplify your problem massively, for example, just have 2 data columns.

Comment: let me clarify.

1) key1,2,4,6
2) the next occurence of key1 is
   key1,3,5,7
3) the next occurrence of key1 is
   key1,4,6,8
4) the next occurence of key1 is
   key1,6,8,10

Ideally, the perl script should print

key1: Diff from previous record is 1 (3-2), 1(5-4), 1(7-6)
key1: Diff from previous record is 1 (4-3), 1(6-5), 1(8-7)
key1: Diff from previous record is 2 (6-4), 2(8-6), 2(10-8)

This is very simple example. The csv file has key2,key3... keyn  with each key repeating so many times. I need the difference for all keys (current versus previous record).

Comment: @need_help - please put the clarification into the question itself by editing it. Comments are very poorly formatted and yor comment above is basically unreadable, sorry.

Comment: i apologize but i'm a new poster. I'll edit the question going forward.

Answer (score 2):

You can try doing:

```
    # get the key.
    my $key = shift @array;

    # see if the key is already seen.
    if(exists $hash{$key} ) {
            # get ref to previous record of this key.
            my $ref = $hash{$key};

            # print key.
            print "$key,";

            # a new array.
            my @new_array;

            # populate the new array.
            for(my $i=0;$i<=$#array;$i++) {
                    $new_array[$i] = $array[$i] - $$ref[$i];
            }

            # join the array elements with comma.
            print join",",@new_array;
            print "\n";
    }

    # add/replace the current array as value for the current key.
    $hash{$key} = \@array;
```

[You can see the working code here](http://www.ideone.com/GcR3C)

Comment: Thank you very much, codaddict. This worked perfectly except for the first key.

Answer (score 0):

My try:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV_XS;

use Math::Matrix;



my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({binary => 1});

my %hash;

my @results;

open my $fh, '<', 'file1.csv' or die "Cannot open: $!";

while (my $line = <$fh>) {

  if ($csv->parse($line)) {

    my @array = $csv->fields;
    my $key = shift @array;

    if (! exists $hash{$key}) {
      $hash{$key} = \@array;
      next;
    }



    my $previous_record = Math::Matrix->new($hash{$key});
    my $current_record = Math::Matrix->new(\@array);

    my $new_record = $previous_record->add($current_record->negative);

    push @results, @$new_record;

    $hash{$key} = \@array;



  }
  else {
    my $err = $csv->error_input;
    print "error parsing: $err\n";
  }

}
```

Comment: This also worked. But, it calculated the difference between previous record and current record. I guess that i did not explain the problem more accurately. Thank you very much for the effort.